# PostgreSQL User data type in C Error: is only a shell

Tags: c, postgresql, shell

I'm creating an extension for PostgreSQL. I created the new Complex data type, as per PostgreSQL documentation show. Follow the code:

```c
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "libpq/pqformat.h" /* needed for send/recv functions */

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

typedef struct Complex {
    double x, y;
} Complex;


/**************************
 * Input/Output functions *
 *************************/

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(complex_in);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(complex_out);

Datum complex_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)  {
    char *str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    double x, y;
    Complex *result;

    if (sscanf(str, " ( %lf , %lf )", &x, &y) != 2)
        ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION),
                 errmsg("invalid input syntax for complex: \"%s\"",
                        str)));

    result = (Complex *) palloc(sizeof(Complex));
    result->x = x;
    result->y = y;
    PG_RETURN_POINTER(result);
}

Datum complex_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    Complex *complex = (Complex *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    char    *result;

    result = psprintf("(%g,%g)", complex->x, complex->y);
    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);
}
```

And SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION complex_in(cstring)
RETURNS complex
AS '$libdir/complex'
LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION complex_out(complex)
RETURNS cstring
AS '$libdir/complex'
LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION complex_recv(internal)
RETURNS complex
AS '$libdir/complex'
LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION complex_send(complex)
RETURNS bytea
AS '$libdir/complex'
LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE TYPE complex (
    internallength = 16,
    input = complex_in,
    output = complex_out,
    receive = complex_recv,
    send = complex_send,
    alignment = double
);
```

And Makefile

```
EXTENSION = complex        # the extensions name
DATA = complex--0.0.1.sql  # script files to install
MODULES = complex          # our c module file to build

# postgres build stuff
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

I create the new type using `CREATE TYPE complex`, but when I use the new data type the following error appears

`ERROR:  type "complex" is only a shell.`

Is there anything wrong with the codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html).

First, you create a *shell type* with a statement like

```
CREATE TYPE complex;
```

That is just a name and cannot be used yet. Think of it as a function declaration in C.

Next you create the type input and output functions with `CREATE FUNCTION`, using the shell type in the definitions.

Finally you complete the type definition with a statement like

```
CREATE TYPE complex (
   internallength = 16,
   input = complex_in,
   output = complex_out,
   receive = complex_recv,
   send = complex_send,
   alignment = double
);
```

This can be compared to a function definition in C. Now the type can be used.

From your error message it looks like you forgot to run that final `CREATE TYPE` statement.

Comment: My code has as input and output functions. And I also used the CREATE TYPE complex, as you say.

Comment: Looks like it worked now. I first used CREATE A EXTENSION complex and then use the type. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: If you packaged it into an extension, you'd have to examine the extension SQL file for problems.